# NoSuchMethodError: No static method ()Ljava/lang/Thread

Tags: android, multithreading, firebase, crash, nosuchmethoderror

Firebase reported this crash 600+ times today all by one single user, I don't understand what logs say. Can anyone tell me what METHOD is missing in Thread? What maybe the problem? thx

crash log:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method ()Ljava/lang/Thread; in class Ljava/lang/Thread; or its super classes (declaration of 'java.lang.Thread' appears in /system/framework/core-oj.jar)
           at bap.run(bap.java:1)
           at bbe.run(bbe.java)
           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

device info:

```
Device
Brand:samsung
Model:Galaxy J7(2016)
Orientation: Portrait
RAM free: 467.38 MB
Disk free: 520.28 MB
Operating System
Version:8.1.0
Orientation: Portrait
Rooted:No
Crash
Date:May 26, 2021, 12:01:12 AM
App version:v1.5.7 (132)
```